# Ubuntu boot stuck and GParted live not launching

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, uefi, gparted

I've just run out of space on my root directory, so I wanted to shrink the 12GB swap partition to get more space using Gparted Live USB. This wasn't my first time using this tool and I have already changed the Ubuntu partitions once, but haven't encountered any problems. This time, however, I launched GParted with default settings, but it crashed with logs flashing by too fast for me to read them and I had to force shutdown my computer. Unfortunately, now when I try to boot Ubuntu, it gets stuck at "start job running for dev-disk-by/" and waiting 10 minutes doesn't help, despite the fact that it displays a timer stuck at 22s/1min30s.

GParted was installed on my pendrive with UNetBootin, but then I tried Rufus on Windows and now when I try to boot it I get a short output saying that the Volume is corrupt and \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi could not be loaded.

I'm using a dual-boot 18.04 LTS setup with Windows 10 (which boots fine) on an ASUS ZenBook UX433FN.

I would really appreciate the help, since I need my sweet system back for my studies

Answer (score 0):

- Use ubuntu installation image and run **Try Ubuntu without installing** option
- Crate mount point folder `sudo mkdir /mnt/rootpartition`
- Mount your root partition `sudo mount /dev/sdX /mnt/rootpartition -t ext4 -o rw`
- Clear `/tmp` folder by `sudo rm -fr /mnt/rootpartition/tmp/*`
- Clear apt cached archives: `sudo rm -fr /mnt/rootpartition/var/cache/apt/archives/*`
- Unmount your rootpartition `sudo umount /mnt/rootpartition`
- Run gparted, shrink your swap file size and append it to your root partition.
- Get your partitions new UUIDs if they changed by a command execution: `blkid`
- Mount your root partition to `/mnt/rootpartition`
- Modify your `/mnt/rootpartition/etc/fstab` replacing old UUIDs by new ones if they changed.

Comment: Unfortunately, the image doesn't boot:

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/LpvwVuy

Comment: When do you get this errors? During normal boot or during Try Ubuntu without installing?

Comment: Try Ubuntu without installing